# Assigning value to each number from TSpinEdit

Tags: delphi-7

I have a TSpinEdit named **seVal**, its min value is at 0 and the max is 10. I need to assign a value to each number, except 0 which needs to report an error message, and then display that value in a Label. I've not delt with TSpinEdit's that much so any coding to do with them is not familiar to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case seVal.Value of
  0: Label1.Caption := ...;
  1: Label1.Caption := ...;
  2: Label1.Caption := ...;
  ...
end;
```

Or:

```
const
  LabelValues: array[0..10] of String = ('...', '...', ...);

Label1.Caption := LabelValues[seVal.Value];
```